Positioning the Sefer Torah poles
I was recently told that while we do gelilah - rolling the Sefer Torah - we always mean to position the "Bereshit" pole higher than "Devarim" pole.
Is there any Halacha about it? any sources would be appreciated

Often the "beginning" roller will have two disks at the top one at the bottom, and the "end" roller will have the opposite, so that's the only way to put them together neatly. The question remains why it's standard to design them that way.

An early source of this custom can be found in Yosif Ometz 525, the book of R' Yuzpa Hahn (–1637) from Frankfurt:

וידקדק שיהיה הצד של בראשית עליון על צד השנייה. וכן הוא המנהג בכל מקומות מושבות בני ישראל.‏
And he should be careful that the side of Bereishit should be above the other side. And this is the custom of all places settled by the children of Israel.

Unfortunately he doesn't give further references. I have also found an article of the Rivevot Efrayim in Noam Vol. 10 about the gelilah. In Section 13 he discusses that he has asked many rabbanim who gave various kabbalistic reasons besides stressing that the right side has a general precedence over the left side, but he concludes that the best source is the cited part of Yosif Ometz.
